# Error: 'colour_ramp' is not an exported object from 'namespace:scales'

Tags: leaflet

'colour_ramp' is not an exported object from 'namespace:scales' in leaflet packages. I've already installed leaflet in r. How to solve the problem? Thank you!

My code is following,

```
library(leaflet)

# Set up the color palette and breaks
colors <- c("#FFEDA0", "#FED976", "#FEB24C", "#FD8D3C", "#FC4E2A", "#E31A1C",          "#BD0026", "#800026")
bins <- c(-Inf, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Inf) + 0.00000001
pal <- colorBin(colors, NULL, bins)
> pal <- colorBin(colors, NULL, bins)
Error: 'colour_ramp' is not an exported object from 'namespace:scales'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need scales version >= [0.2.5](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/index.html). See [Joe Chengs comment here](https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap/issues/16). Ran into the same.